# Recognising the titleLabel of a button in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6

I am writing an iPad app that has a Cancel button on a view controller. When the work on the controller is finished the labelText changes from "Cancel" to "Done". Therefore I only want the alert to show when the labelTitle is still "Cancel". If it is "Done" I just want the controller to dismiss. Here is the code:

```
NSLog(@"%@",closeButton.titleLabel.text);

if (closeButton.titleLabel.text = @"Cancel")
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"i-observe"
message:@"Are you sure that you want to cancel?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"no" otherButtonTitles:@"yes", nil];
[alert show];
} 
else
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  
}
```

What happens is that the alert appears in both cases ("Cancel" and "Done"). However in the NSLog it shows that the titleLabel has changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are setting the text to "Cancel" within your if statement. So, your if statement logic says "if the title text is successfully set to 'Cancel', then display the alert." The comparison operator is `==`, not `=`.

Second, you do not want to compare two different text objects with the `==` operator. You want to use `isEqualToString:` like this:

```
if ([closeButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) { ... }
```

Comment: The text is not changed in the if statement however changing it to isEqualToString worked a treat - many thanks. Much appreciated.

Comment: You misunderstand me. When you type `closeButton.titleLabel.text = @"Cancel"` you are assigning text to the `closeButton` title label. That is what you had in your if condition previously, so you were assigning text from within your if condition. Within the if condition, you should use `==` to compare two objects if you want to know if they are literally the same location in memory. If you want to know if the two objects are functionally the same, but possibly different instances, you use `isEqual:`. Strings have the specialized `isEqualToString:` method.

Comment: I see - I think. I tried == but that did not work though. Are you saying that == is the same as isEqualToString?

Comment: No, I am saying the two are very different. In order to understand why, you need to do some reading on pointers and understand that most of the time in Objective C you are working with object pointers. If you want to know if two objects are exactly the same object, then you use `==`. However, often you just want to know if two objects are **equivalent** to each other. This is what `isEqaul:` and `isEqualToString:` are for. You want to test if the string displayed on the button contains the same characters as the string @"Cancel" even though they are two different objects.

Comment: If you do some googling for "Objective C pointers" or "C pointers" you will come up with a lot of good reading on the topic. One place to get a quick intro to pointers is [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/pointers-in-objective-c/225700236). Read that and you will understand what `==` means. Most of the time, you will want to test for object equivalence rather than pointer equality so you will use `isEqual:` and related methods.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Would it be fair to say therefore that a pointer is what I might consider a variable in other circumstances but with additional properties in objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "==" to compare strings. You use isEqualToString, like this:

```
if ([closeButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
```